# Checking network status in Swift, observer does not get called

Tags: swift

I have imported **Reachability.h .m** files like written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift/24005242#24005242) into my Swift project, but observer / event handler will not get called after start, why?

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "reachabilityChanged:", name: kReachabilityChangedNotification, object: nil)

    let hostReachability = Reachability(hostName: "www.apple.com");
    hostReachability.startNotifier();

    return true
}

func reachabilityChanged(note: NSNotification) { // <- DOES NOT GET CALLED

    let reachability: Reachability = note.object as Reachability;

    if(reachability.currentReachabilityStatus() != .NotReachable) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Its a problem in your Reachability class, Try this one https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability

Comment: is it an iOS8 / Swift related fix? because the same Reachability.h .m was working for iOS7 / Objective-C

Comment: Reachability object is deallocated (since it is an autoreleased object and also not holding strong reference)

Comment: This might be of use… https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `Reachability` object returned is an autoreleased object , so it has deallocated hence notification is not triggering . You can fix by keeping a strong reference to it.

create a property to hold `Reachability` object

```
var reachability:Reachability?

 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "reachabilityChanged:", name:kReachabilityChangedNotification, object: nil)

        reachability = Reachability(hostName: "www.apple.com");
        reachability?.startNotifier();

        return true
    }
```

This will fix your problem.

The observer's name is changed from ReachabilityChangedNotification to kReachabilityChangedNotification. Notice the "k"

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. "reachabilityChanged" is still never called.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, you need to maintain a strong reference to the Reachability object. If you aren't checking a particular host, then call reachabilityForInternetConnection:

```
let internetReachability = Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "reachabilityChanged:", name: kReachabilityChangedNotification, object: internetReachability)
    internetReachability.startNotifier()
    let hasInternet = internetReachability.currentReachabilityStatus().value == 0 ? false : true

    // Save to user defaults, log to console, etc.

    return true
}

func reachabilityChanged(note: NSNotification) {
    var hasInternet = Bool()
    if let reachability = note.object as? Reachability {
        hasInternet = internetReachability.currentReachabilityStatus().value == 0 ? false : true
    }

    // Update user defaults, log to console, show error message, etc.
}
```

Comment: what does one need to import for reachability in swift?

Comment: do i have to bridge to objective-c to use reachablilty?

Comment: Though its late for me to answer your reachability import doubt @EladBenda.But anyway,for working with Reachability.h and .m files in swift.You have to use bridging header file in swift.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 3+, use below code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(checkForReachability(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.reachabilityChanged, object: nil)
    reachability = Reachability.forInternetConnection()
    reachability.startNotifier()

    return true
}

 // MARK:
// MARK: Check Internet Status
func checkForReachability(notification:NSNotification)
{
    let networkReachability = notification.object as! Reachability;
    let remoteHostStatus = networkReachability.currentReachabilityStatus()

    if (remoteHostStatus == NotReachable)
    {
        print("Not Reachable")
    }
    else
    {
        print("Reachable")
    }
}
```